# No API Found in ROS Wiki mirror

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I've just followed this [tutorial](http://answers.ros.org/question/10010/create-a-rosorg-wiki-mirror/) to create an offline mirror of the ROS Wiki and API, but the API is only populated with diamondback and independent API folders. Where have Fuerte, Groovy and Hydro gone? It there something wrong with the mirror scripts or the website?

in folder roswiki/doc I've executed

```
$ ls -lah
drwxrwxr-x 4 miquel miquel 4,0K ago 28 23:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 miquel miquel 656K oct 25 14:01 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 miquel miquel   10 ene 30  2013 api -> groovy/api
drwxrwxr-x 3 miquel miquel 4,0K jul 10  2011 diamondback
lrwxrwxrwx 1 miquel miquel   26 ago 28 23:40 electric -> /home/rosbot/docs/electric
lrwxrwxrwx 1 miquel miquel   24 ago 28 23:40 fuerte -> /home/rosbot/docs/fuerte
lrwxrwxrwx 1 miquel miquel   24 ago 28 23:40 groovy -> /home/rosbot/docs/groovy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 miquel miquel   23 ago 28 23:41 hydro -> /home/rosbot/docs/hydro
drwxrwxr-x 3 miquel miquel 4,0K ene 30  2013 independent
```

I don't have any *rosbot* user in my laptop!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94246/no-api-found-in-ros-wiki-mirror/) by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1471 on 2013-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki dumps you referenced do not contain the full API doc folders. Simply because we are talking about hundreds of GB of data here. Currently there is no way to mirror the complete API docs data efficiently.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-10-28**:
I'm leaving a proper internet connection for some weeks and, at least, I'd like to have roscpp, rospy, tf and other core documentations. Do you know any way to get them?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-10-28**:
You could clone the repos and generate the docs locally.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-10-28**:
It is also flat file, so something like http://scrapy.org/ might work.